# Global name 'parseLog' not defined Python 2.7

Tags: python, class, global-variables

I have read through similar topics and I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong. I get the error, global name 'parseLog' is not defined. Also, I've been fumbling to get the code formatted correctly on here, but everything is indented properly in my editor, just got annoyed trying to make it so on here.

```
import urllib2
import re
import json
class parseLog:
    def __init__(self):
        ''' Get access log location and pattern(Common Log Format)'''

    self.apacheLog = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/access.log'
    self.data = urllib2.urlopen(self.apacheLog)
    self.parts = [
    r'(?P<host>\S+)', 
    r'\S+', 
    r'(?P<user>\S+)', 
    r'\[(?P<time>.+)\]',
    r'"(?P<request>.+)"', 
    r'(?P<status>[0-9]+)', 
    r'(?P<size>\S+)', 
    r'"(?P<referer>.*)"', 
    r'"(?P<agent>.*)"', 
    ]

    self.pat = re.compile(r'\s+'.join(self.parts)+r'\s*\Z')

def rescheck(result):
    '''Check for absent refer page'''
    if result["referer"] == "-":
        result["referer"] = None
    return
def getIPinfo(IP,result):
    '''Get lat,long,org,and ISP using IP address from log record'''
    apiURL = 'http://ip-api.com/json/'+IP            
    getResp = urllib2.urlopen(apiURL)
    jsonResp = json.load(getResp)
    result["lat"] = jsonResp['lat']
    result["long"] = jsonResp['lon']
    result["org"] = jsonResp['org']
    result["ISPname"] = jsonResp['isp']
    finalKeys = ["time","request","referer","host","org","lat","long","ISPname"]
    finalDict = {x: result[x] for x in finalKeys if x in result}
    print finalDict
    return finalDict
def main():
    with open('C:\Users\Brandon\Downloads\LogCopy1.txt','a') as f:
        for line in parseLog.data:
            match = parseLog.pat.match(line)
            result = match.groupdict()
            theIP = result["host"]
            print theIP
            parseLog.rescheck(result)
            dictToWrite = parseLog.getIPinfo(theIP,result)
            f.write(str(dictToWrite))
            #print str(dictToWrite)
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parseLog is a class.  In order to access a the data member or method of a class in python (unless it's static), you'll first need to create an instance of the class:

```
pl = parseLog()
```

And then to update your code:

```
def main():
    pl = parseLog()
    with open('C:\Users\Brandon\Downloads\LogCopy1.txt','a') as f:
        for line in pl.data:
            match = pl.pat.match(line)
            result = match.groupdict()
            theIP = result["host"]
            print theIP
            rescheck(result)
            dictToWrite = getIPinfo(theIP,result)
            f.write(str(dictToWrite))
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, when I try this. Does everything else look okay?

Comment: @RagePwn your implementation of \_\_init\_\_ is unindented.  That'll cause problems if it isn't a mistake in the post?

Comment: It is only like that in the post. All the definitions are indented properly in my code, I was just having a tough time getting it formatted correctly in my first post.

Comment: @RagePwn is there any other code you didn't post?  Your posted code with the change in my answer compiles fine for me (although your URL gives an HTTP error 400)

Comment: Nope, thats everything. Real URL = https://raw.githubusercontent.com/silicon-valley-data-science/datasets/master/access.log

Comment: @RagePwn a couple other things: rescheck and getIPInfo aren't members of parseLog, so I removed the use of pl there from my answer.  With this fix, everything seems to be running fine for me.  Although that wouldn't cause a 'parseLog' not defined error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70989/discussion-between-ragepwn-and-aquigs).